# Creating an efficient tiled background in sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

What I have created in my SpriteKit project is a large two-dimensionally tiled background made up of about 160 sprite nodes. But to me, this seems extremely inefficient.

Would putting these nodes under a single parent make them more efficient? I would assume not and in that case is their a way to combine the textures themselves into a single node at run time?

I would simply use an image editor to tile these images but the size of said background will change between devices, and due to other factors within my project.

Comment: _"I would simply use an image editor to tile these images but the size of said background will change between devices, and..."_  And what?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Whoops didn't see it got cut off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do, in your loading phase,  create the 160 sprite nodes needed to make your background under 1 parent node, then call `let texture = scene.view.textureFromNode(parentNode)`, and use this texture for your BG sprite.  When the loading phase ends,  the 160 sprites should get destroyed